# R Scatter plot - can't see my "red"abline but can see my "blue"one

Tags: r

Can't seem to get a red line to appear (haha) can someone help pls? (R)

Thanks

A

```
df2 = filter(df1,EXP >= 30)
df3 = filter(df1,EXP < 30)
model5= lm(EXP~LWAGE,data= df2)
model6= lm(EXP~LWAGE,data= df3)
with(df2,plot(EXP, LWAGE))
abline(lm(EXP~LWAGE,data= df2),col="red") 
with(df3,plot(EXP, LWAGE))
abline(lm(EXP~LWAGE,data= df3),col="blue")
```

Comment: hi and welcome to stackoverflow. 
It is hard to help you with this particular problem if you do not provide your data.
You can use `dput(df1)` to share your data.

Comment: The second plot starts a new graphics device. Before calling `plot` the second time, call `par(new = TRUE)`.

Comment: Why do you specifically create `model5` and then re-create `lm(...)` in the abline?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I think a better recommendation is to *not plot* the second time, as it's a perfect duplicate of the first. If it did have different points, I'd suggest using `points` instead, as that will preserve the axis and limits of the first plot (whereas `par(new=TRUE)` can easily have different axis labels/limits).

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. If you do, I will reopen, following @r2evans comments.

Comment: While that dupe answer technically meets the needs here, I discourage the use of `par(new=TRUE)` to any beginning R user that is not well-prepared to deal with its risks. In a perfect scenario, all axes and axis-labels and axis-ticks are double-plotted, which while inefficient does no harm. If *anything* is different enough to cause a slight shift in the axis limits, or if one of the axes is actually a different variable, then the plot can be unreadable. `par(new=TRUE)` has very specific uses, and I don't think it should be a first solution for most users.

Comment: @r2evansThat's precisely why I've asked the OP to post data. The points can be plotted all at once, colored by `c("blue","red")[(EXP>=30)+1]`, and then the regression lines.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, the comment was more for the OP than for you. I strongly suspect that you know the nuances :-)

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for the help: I'll post the data below here (I'm new to SO so please bear with me haha)

Comment: ahh actually it says I've used too many characters - not sure how to just send the csv file here :s